# Asserting throws in tape - node

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, assert, node.js-tape

So I am trying to test out a function, it is a client-side function(un-finish) which is why it is embedded in the test itself(until I can figure out a better solution).

The problem I am having is when I test to see if the function is throwing a TypeError.

I understand the problem is because it is testing the return value and not the function itself, I am unsure how to work around this.

Any and All help is appreciated!

### Tape

---

#### test.js

```
var test  = require('tape');


test('GenerateRandomNumber Tests', function(assert){  

  /**
   * Generates a random number between the min/max
   * @param {int} the min value 
   * @param {int} the max value 
   * @param {array} list of values already stored
   * @return {mixed} int if success, false if exception thrown
  **/
  var GenerateRandomNumber = function( min, max, tickets ){
        
    try{
      
      if(!tickets instanceof Array){
        throw new TypeError();
      }
      
      min = (min) || 0;
      max = (max) || 200;
      
      var n = 0;

      n = ~~(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
      
      if(tickets.indexOf(n) === 1){
        GenerateRandomNumber(min, max);
      }
      
      return n;
      
    }catch(e){ return false; } 
    
  };
  
  assert.plan(4);
  
  
  var t1 = GenerateRandomNumber(0, 300, null);
  assert.equal(typeof t1, "boolean", "Should return a boolean - false");
  
  var t2 = GenerateRandomNumber(0, 300, [0,1,2,3,4]);
  assert.equal(typeof t2, "number", "Should return a typeof number");
  
  // HELP
  assert.throws(GenerateRandomNumber(0, 300, null), TypeError, "Should throw typeError");
  
  var t4 = GenerateRandomNumber(null, null, [0,1,2,3,4]);
  assert.equal(typeof t4, "number", "Should return a typeof number");
  
  
});
```

Comment: tape-catch might help? link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tape-catch

Comment: I will look into that, thank you @JamesonYu

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? I ran this and all the tests passed. Are you expecting `assert.throws` to fail?

Comment: If you comment out `throw new TypeError`, the tests will still pass. which is not the desired behavior. I'm sure the `assert.throws` method is evaluating the return value and not evaluating the function itself. @cojomojo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you're first problem is that `!tickets instanceof Array` is not the logic you want. What that does is first executes the not operation on `tickets` and then tests if that is an `instanceof Array`. So what you actually want is:

```
if(!(tickets instanceof Array)){
   throw new TypeError();
}
```

The next issue is that, like you said, you are getting the return value of `GenerateRandomNumber`, which if an error is thrown, is `false` not a TypeError. If you want to keep your try/catch and return false in `GenerateRandomNumber` then you don't need the `throws` test but rather something like:

`assert.equal(GenerateRandomNumber(0, 300, null), false, "Should catch the TypeError and return false)`

If you want to use `assert.throws` then you need to remove the try/catch from `GenerateRandomNumber` and instead do something like this:

```
var test  = require('tape');


test('GenerateRandomNumber Tests', function(assert){  

  /**
   * Generates a random number between the min/max
   * @param {int} the min value 
   * @param {int} the max value 
   * @param {array} list of values already stored
   * @return {mixed} int if success, false if exception thrown
  **/
  var GenerateRandomNumber = function( min, max, tickets ){
      if(!(tickets instanceof Array)){
        throw new TypeError('error');
      }

      min = (min) || 0;
      max = (max) || 200;

      var n = 0;

      n = ~~(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 

      if(tickets.indexOf(n) === 1){
        GenerateRandomNumber(min, max);
      }

      return n;
  };

  assert.plan(3);

  var t2 = GenerateRandomNumber(0, 300, [0,1,2,3,4]);
  assert.equal(typeof t2, "number", "Should return a typeof number");

  // You must wrap GenerateRandomNumber from within another function 
  //so that the error being thrown doesn't cause the program to exit
  assert.throws(() => GenerateRandomNumber(0, 300, null), /error/, "Should throw typeError");

  var t4 = GenerateRandomNumber(null, null, [0,1,2,3,4]);
  assert.equal(typeof t4, "number", "Should return a typeof number");


});
```

I used the option to pass a RegExp because tape's matching of errors when passing a function as expected is quite strange (see [this issue](https://github.com/substack/tape/issues/182)). Im looking into an option for doing it this way still, but hopefully this helps you for now.